# Unable to send mail through php mail in OpenShift

Tags: php, email

I've been trying out some php codes and I cannot able to send mail through the following code. I've sent some days before but now the `mail()` function returns true but the mail is not in the recipient's inbox. Here's the code:

```
$to = "test@example.com";
$subject = "Testing Emails";
$emailBody = "Hello";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Test <no-reply@example.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: no-reply@example.com"."\r\n";
$mail = mail($to,$subject,$emailBody,$headers);

if($mail){    
    echo 'Successfully sent';
} else {
    echo 'Failed to send';
}
```

Note: I've replaced all the `to` address with an original address.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP [mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function page

Note:

```
If messages are not received, try using a LF (\n) only. 
Some Unix mail transfer agents (most notably » qmail) replace LF by CRLF 
automatically (which leads to doubling CR if CRLF is used). 
This should be a last resort, as it does not comply with » RFC 2822.
```

Comment: On a new day the mail might have a different routing on the net and the behavior may differ. Try to change the code `as a last resort`